# Excel VBA - Populate a Combobox given selection of another Combobox

Tags: excel, combobox, filter, vba

I am trying to populate a second combobox given the selection of a first combobox. The first combobox is the name of all the columns on the sheet. The second combobox should display all of the values in that column except for duplicates. The code below populates combobox1. I am struggling with how to take data out of a column given the varying column name. Thank you for any help.

```
Dim myArray As Variant

lastcol = Sheets(4).Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
With Sheets(4)
Set SourceRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, lastcol))
End With
myArray = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(SourceRng)

With Me.ComboBox1
.List = myArray
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to get the `listindex` of `combobox1`. Keep in mind that the ListIndex is 0-Based while Excel Rows and Columns are not:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_AfterUpdate()

Dim selectedCol as Variant
selectedCol = Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex + 1

Set SourceRng = ws.Range(Cells(2, selectedCol), Cells(4, selectedCol))

Me.ComboBox2.List = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(SourceRng)

End Sub
```

To get rid of the duplicate values and junk: `Set SourceRng = ws.Range(Cells(varRow, Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex + 1), Cells(varRow2, Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex + 1)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:= selectedCol, Header:=xlNo`

Here is a workaround for removing the duplicates. Using the RemoveDuplicates function of the Range class will delete your rows, and I'm assuming you don't want that:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_AfterUpdate()

    Dim colSelect As Integer
    colSelect = Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex + 1

    Set SourceRng = ws.Range(Cells(2, colSelect), Cells(5, colSelect))

    SourceRng.Sort SourceRng, xlDescending

    Dim c
    For Each c In SourceRng.Cells
        If c.Value  c.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
            Me.ComboBox2.AddItem c.Value
        End If
    Next

    'You would take out the array and assigning it to the Combobox2.List

End Sub
```

Comment: This is working pretty well, got it to auto adjust to length with some additional code. Now just to get rid of duplicates and empties.

Comment: Range(Cells(rowHere,colHere),Cells(rowHere,colHere)).RemoveDuplicates

Comment: Sorry, a little new to this. How do I incorporate this into the other code? I can't get it to remove anything so far.

Comment: I added that into my answer. It should work with setting the SourceRng variable

Comment: That's what I thought but when I added it on to the end it says type mismatch.

Comment: I worked out a workaround. Instead of converting the range to an array, just loop through the range (after sorting) and only add the unique values.

Comment: This is working great! Just to let you know your code is missing an operator two lines below the Dim c line. I figured it was <> so it worked. One more question though, is there a way to sort the results in combobox2 alphabetically?

Comment: There's always a way to sort it. Just reverse the sort is one way. Also, I didn't show it in my code but it is good practice to use Option Explicit in your code modules. This makes sure you're declaring all your variables. Also (again I didn't do it): Make sure all variables in a sub/module are declared at the beginning so you have them all nicely grouped.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. Everything is working wonderfully now.